# Show modal before main screen loads in react-native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show a non-animating modal before my main screen loads in my react-native app. Basically I want to check if a user is logged in, and if there is not a logged in user show a login screen on a modal view.

The trouble is my main screen appears for a split second before my modal instead of the modal showing up first. I am new to react/javascript in general and am not sure how to solve this.

I placed my login check in componentWillLoad thinking this would occur before the component is rendered on screen, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Check if a user is signed in
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log("Signed in");
        this.setState({modalVisible: false});
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log("Not signed in");
        this.setState({modalVisible: true});
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>

        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: Things,
            title: 'MyScene',
          }}
          style={{flex: 1}}
        />

        <Modal
          animationType={"none"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
          <Login />
        </Modal>

      </View>

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should render your modal component if login is required and style your modal component properly. I mean, if(this.state.requireLogin) return(<Modal/>) else return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is appearing for a split second because `onAuthStateChanged` call is `asynchronous` and react will not wait for that to complete and it moves on so your rendering happens before firebase returns. So to solve this you have to wait till firebase returns. To achieve this let's use state. Will create one state variable called `isFirebaseReturned`. In the below code `react` will render `NavigatorIos` or `Modal` only if `isFirebaseReturned = true`

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    isFirebaseReturned:false
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Check if a user is signed in
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
        console.log("Signed in");
        this.setState({modalVisible: false,isFirebaseReturned:true});
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log("Not signed in");
        this.setState({modalVisible: true,isFirebaseReturned:true});
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
      {this.state.isFirebaseReturned &&
        <NavigatorIOS
          initialRoute={{
            component: Things,
            title: 'MyScene',
          }}
          style={{flex: 1}}
        />

        <Modal
          animationType={"none"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
          <Login />
        </Modal>
      }
      </View>

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Alright! that worked. I had to wrap the navigator and modal in a View tag, but that seems to work fine. I dont understand what is happening with the logical statement though. could you explain this line {this.state.isFirebaseReturned && ...

Comment: I ended up just using an if else statement since it seems a bit more explicit than using the logical condition. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @StonePreston that logic is pure Javascript. You have to learn more about how boolean thing works in Javascript. In that line React will read <Navigator only if this.state.isFirebaseReturned is true